# ios uiwebview in uitableview prevents scroll/touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have uiwebview in uitableview cell. I load HTML string in uiwebview. I have set viewport tag on html content. But when i zoom the webview & then scroll the webview vertically, it doesn't scroll.

```
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\"</head><body>%@</body></html>",content];
[cell.webview loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
cell.webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant code?

Comment: cell.webView.scrollView.bounce=yes; may this help u

Comment: Let's see the whole function, but it sounds like the scrolling is behaving as expected. When you zoom back out to normal, does the tableview scroll vertically again?

Comment: yes, When I zoom back out to normal, the tableview scroll vertically again. the only issue comes is it doesnt scroll when it is zoomed in...